# Collapsing vertical space in longtblr

Tags: vertical, tabularray

I have a `tabularray` `longtblr` made up of groups of rows that are separated by extra vertical space. When a group ends up at the end of a page of the table, it creates an unsightly space between that group and the `\hline` at the bottom.

Is there a way to collapse the extra vertical space when it occurs at the bottom of a page?

This example code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}{colspec=lX,width=\textwidth,rowsep=0pt}
  \hline
  Head \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{Group 1} \\*
  & 1.1 \\[2ex]
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{Group 2} \\*
  & 2.1 \\[2ex]
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{Group 3} \\*
  & 3.1 \\[2ex]
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{Group 4} \\*
  & 4.1 \\[2ex]
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{Group 5} \\*
  & 5.1 \\[2ex]
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{Group 6} \\*
  & 6.1 \\[2ex]
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{Group 7} \\*
  & 7.1 \\[2ex]
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{Group 8} \\*
  & 8.1 \\[2ex]
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{Group 9} \\*
  & 9.1 \\[2ex]
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{Group 10} \\*
  & 10.1 \\[2ex]
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{Group 11} \\*
  & 1.1 \\[2ex]            
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{Group 12} \\*
  & 2.1 \\[2ex]            
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{Group 13} \\*
  & 3.1 \\[2ex]            
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{Group 14} \\*
  & 4.1 \\[2ex]            
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{Group 15} \\*
  & 5.1 \\[2ex]            
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{Group 16} \\*
  & 6.1 \\[2ex]            
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{Group 17} \\*
  & 7.1 \\[2ex]            
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{Group 18} \\*
  & 8.1 \\[2ex]            
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{Group 19} \\*
  & 9.1 \\
  \hline
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

Results in:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) You may replace vertical space below the rows with white hlines; hlines at page breaks will be removed.

(2) You may replace `\multicolumn` with `\SetCell`; `\multicolumn` command will be removed in version 2022.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}{colspec=lX,width=\textwidth,rowsep=0pt}
  \hline
  Head \\
  \hline
  \SetCell[c=2]{l} Group 1 \\*
  & 1.1 \\
  \hline[white,2ex]
  \SetCell[c=2]{l} Group 2 \\*
  & 2.1 \\
  \hline[white,2ex]
  \SetCell[c=2]{l} Group 3 \\*
  & 3.1 \\
  \hline[white,2ex]
  \SetCell[c=2]{l} Group 4 \\*
  & 4.1 \\
  \hline[white,2ex]
  \SetCell[c=2]{l} Group 5 \\*
  & 5.1 \\
  \hline[white,2ex]
  \SetCell[c=2]{l} Group 6 \\*
  & 6.1 \\
  \hline[white,2ex]
  \SetCell[c=2]{l} Group 7 \\*
  & 7.1 \\
  \hline[white,2ex]
  \SetCell[c=2]{l} Group 8 \\*
  & 8.1 \\
  \hline[white,2ex]
  \SetCell[c=2]{l} Group 9 \\*
  & 9.1 \\
  \hline[white,2ex]
  \SetCell[c=2]{l} Group 10 \\*
  & 10.1 \\
  \hline[white,2ex]
  \SetCell[c=2]{l} Group 11 \\*
  & 1.1 \\
  \hline[white,2ex]            
  \SetCell[c=2]{l} Group 12 \\*
  & 2.1 \\
  \hline[white,2ex]            
  \SetCell[c=2]{l} Group 13 \\*
  & 3.1 \\
  \hline[white,2ex]            
  \SetCell[c=2]{l} Group 14 \\*
  & 4.1 \\
  \hline[white,2ex]            
  \SetCell[c=2]{l} Group 15 \\*
  & 5.1 \\
  \hline[white,2ex]            
  \SetCell[c=2]{l} Group 16 \\*
  & 6.1 \\
  \hline[white,2ex]            
  \SetCell[c=2]{l} Group 17 \\*
  & 7.1 \\
  \hline[white,2ex]            
  \SetCell[c=2]{l} Group 18 \\*
  & 8.1 \\
  \hline[white,2ex]            
  \SetCell[c=2]{l} Group 19 \\*
  & 9.1 \\
  \hline
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) ... Is possible that in future can be add the same features (removing `\hline` at page breaks) to `\addlinespace` ? This features has other rules from `booktabs` library (package) .

Comment: @Zarko It is not a special feature but a normal behavior: at the bottom of pages we always use `\bottomrule` (or the last hline), so we have to remove hlines between rows. In `tabularray` command `\addlinespace` just  increases the `belowsep`; after that we lost the information and can not distinguish between the original size and the increased size. Therefore it is impossible to remove this space.

Answer (score 1):

See, if the following MWE gives what you after:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\bfseries}                    
  \ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChildSelector{eachtwo}
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {2}{2}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Does your table has a caption?}
                    ]
                    {
        colspec = {lX},
        rowsep = 0pt,
        row{eachtwo} = {abovesep=2ex},
        row{1} = {font=\bfseries, rowsep=2pt},
        row{2} = {abovesep=2pt},
                    }
% table body
    \toprule
Head    &       \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   {Group 1} \\*
        & 1.1   \\
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   {Group 2} \\*
        & 2.1   \\
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   {Group 3} \\*
        & 3.1   \\
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   {Group 4} \\*
        & 4.1   \\
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   {Group 5} \\*
        & 5.1   \\
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   {Group 6} \\*
        & 6.1   \\
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   {Group 7} \\*
        & 7.1   \\
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   {Group 8} \\*
        & 8.1   \\
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   {Group 9} \\*
        & 9.1   \\
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   {Group 10} \\*
        & 10.1  \\
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   {Group 11} \\*
        & 1.1   \\
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   {Group 12} \\*
        & 2.1   \\
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   {Group 13} \\*
        & 3.1   \\
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   {Group 14} \\*
        & 4.1   \\
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   {Group 15} \\*
        & 5.1   \\
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   {Group 16} \\*
        & 6.1   \\
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   {Group 17} \\*
        & 7.1   \\
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   {Group 18} \\*
        & 8.1   \\
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   {Group 19} \\*
        & 9.1   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
From OP comment I conclude, that above MWE is not what he is after. Since from question is unclear, what is a problem, now I guess, that may the following MWE be, what he looking for.

In MWE are in the first four rows grup added variation of possible contents of multi column cells and possible contents in the first column.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\bfseries}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Does your table has a caption?}
                    ]
                    {
        colspec = {l X[font=\linespread{0.84}\selectfont]},
        rowsep = 1pt,
        row{1} = {font=\bfseries, rowsep=2pt},
                     }
% table body
    \toprule
Head    &   some text               \\*
    \midrule
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   Title of group 1 \\*
a       &   \lipsum[1][1-2]         \\
b       &   \lipsum[1][3-4]         \\
c       &   \lipsum[1][5]           \\
    \addlinespace
\SetCell[c=2]{font=\bfseries}   Title of Group 2  
                                (in boldface, if you like)      \\*
a       & 2.1   \\
b       & 2.1   \\
    \addlinespace
\SetCell[c=2]{c}   Title of Group 3 (in center, if you like)    \\* 
a       & 3.1   \\
b       & 3.2   \\
c       & 3.3   \\
d       & 3.4   \\
e       & 3.5   \\
f       & 3.6   \\
    \addlinespace
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   Title Group 4    \\* 
content of cell is unknown
        & \lipsum[66]   \\
    \addlinespace
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   Title Group 5    \\*
        & 5.1   \\
        & 5.2   \\
    \addlinespace
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   Title Group 6    \\*
        & 6.1   \\
    \addlinespace
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   Title Group 7    \\*
        & 7.1   \\
        & 7.2   \\
        & 7.3   \\
    \addlinespace
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   Title Group 8    \\*
        & 8.1   \\
        & 8.2   \\
    \addlinespace
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   Title Group 9    \\*
        & 9.1   \\
        & 9.1   \\
    \addlinespace
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   Title Group 10   \\*
        & 10.1  \\
        & 10.2  \\
        & 10.3  \\
    \addlinespace
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   Title Group 11   \\*
        & 11.1  \\
        & 11.2  \\
    \addlinespace
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   Title Group 12   \\*
        & 12.1  \\
    \addlinespace
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   Title Group 13   \\*
        & 13.1  \\
        & 13.1  \\
        & 13.1  \\
    \addlinespace
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   Title Group 14   \\*
        & 14.1  \\
    \addlinespace
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   Title Group 15   \\*
        & 15.1  \\
        & 15.2  \\
        & 15.3  \\
        & 15.4  \\
    \addlinespace
\SetCell[c=2]{l}   Title Group 16   \\*
        & 16.1  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I should have picked a better example—I need this to work when the groups are uneven sizes, they don't all contain one entry each. If I'm not mistaken, the `abovesep` solution here puts an empty space at the top of the second page instead of the bottom of the first, so I'd definitely prefer something else if possible.

Comment: @MichaelHoffman, sorry how should we know, what you like to have?